# Android - How to parse an XML with colon in tags?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have an XML file like this :

```
<item>  
  <title>...</title>  
  <link>...</link>    
  <pubDate>...</pubDate>
  <description>...</description>
  <media:content url=" ....." type="image/jpg" medium="image" height="270" width="480" />
</item
```

I want to get url in media:content tag.But I don't know how to do this?
Please help me!
Thanks and best regard!!!

Comment: Hint: **url** is an attribute inside **media** tag

Comment: what parser are you using?

Comment: I'm using DOM Parser

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from the title of your question that it is unclear to you that media:content is actually an XML entity (tag) named **'content'**, within namespace **'media'** (hence the column in its name).

What you need to retrieve is the attribute named **'url'** of entity named **'content'** in namespace **'media'**

Typically, for your simple example, code would be similar to the following:

```
rootDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS("media","content")[0].getAttritute("url");
```

Comment: Tags can have a namespace (eg: media). This allows different tags with the same name (eg: content) to co-exist in the same XML document. In XML, this is typically denoted by the tag name being prefixed with "namespace:". In an XML document, there is also a default namespace (no "namespace:" before the tag's name). Tag named 'content' is namespace 'media' is different from tag named 'content' in the default namespace. So you must use namespace-aware functions to retrieve the media:content tag  - hence the use of getElementsByTagNameNS (note  the 'NS' suffix - stands for NameSpace).

Comment: If things are still unclear, please be more specific in what should be clarified.

Comment: Typo in the above. Please read: "Tag named 'content' **in** namespace 'media' is different from tag named 'content' in the default namespace."